# Caching an entire website to speed page load?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

Hi I have a website consisting of multiple pages.

Is it possible to load all the pages to cache when the user enters only the first page?

So going to www.mydomain.com

will preload to cache www.mydomain.com/page1, www.mydomain.com/page2, www.mydomain.com/page3, www.mydomain.com/page4,

So when the user does click on say page 3 it should load instantly?

Comment: Mobile users and those with limited data plan will hate you for that. You can take a look at link prefetching though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You can request those pages with AJAX in the background, then:

- you can hijack the navigation to that page and show the content.
- or if the page is cacheable the browser will show it if you navigate to it.
- or that would kick in the server generation and caching, so the request will be answered faster.